# How can I check if the characters in a string are in a dictionary of values?

Tags: python

I want to check if the characters in any given string are listed in a dictionary of values (as keys) that i have created, how do I do this?

Comment: How about showing the dictionary, some code, and string also??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `any` or `all` depending on whether you want to check if *any* of the characters are in the dictionary, or *all* of them are. Here's some example code that assumes you want `all`:

```
>>> s='abcd'
>>> d={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> all(c in d for c in s)
False
```

Alternatively you might want to get a set of the characters in your string that are also keys in your dictionary:

```
>>> set(s) & d.keys()
{'a', 'c', 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "hello" 
dictionary = {1:"h", 2:"e", 3:"q"}
for c in string:
    if c in dictionary.values():
        print(c, "in dictionary.values!")
```

If you wanted to check if c is in the keys, use dictionary.keys() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
[char for char in your_string if char in your_dict.keys()]
```

this will give you a list of all chars in your string that are present as keys in your dictionary.

Eg.

```
your_dict = {'o':1, 'd':2, 'x':3}
your_string = 'dog'
>>> [char for char in your_string if char in your_dict.keys()]
['d', 'o']
```